# Postgres PREPARE - what does 'session' mean?

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement

I'm looking at the possibility of using Postgres prepared statements, wondering can they improve performance. (We have to use parameters to safeguard against SQL injection, of course, but prepared statements are another thing beyond that.)

(This is in the context of using the C client library, if that matters.)

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html

> Prepared statements only last for the duration of the current database session. When the session ends, the prepared statement is forgotten, so it must be recreated before being used again.

What does 'session' mean?

Does it mean 'open connection'? i.e. between `PQconnectdbParams` and `PQfinish`?

Normal practice is to close the current connection as soon as possible: open connection, query/insert a chunk of data, close it again; don't keep a connection open while waiting for user input, in order to conserve database server resources.

So if 'session' means 'open connection' then it seems to me prepared statements cannot improve performance, because they would be thrown away by the time you would issue the same query again.

But maybe it means something else, or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: "Normal practice is to close the current connection as soon as possible"  That is normal practice for some people/projects.  Surely not for all.

Comment: @jjanes Maybe! Are there projects that keep a connection open while waiting for user input? If so, what is their reasoning about why this is not suboptimal use of database server resources?

Comment: From the docs [Prepare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html): *Prepared statements potentially have the largest performance advantage when a single session is being used to execute a large number of similar statements. The performance difference will be particularly significant if the statements are complex to plan or rewrite, e.g., if the query involves a join of many tables or requires the application of several rules.*

Comment: Worrying about if the CPU, which would otherwise be idle, is being used efficiently is often a poor use of the developers resources.  Sometimes you need to do it, but nor as often as many think. If you use a connection pooler, then that opens up more opportunities, but also more complexity.  Then there is more than one perspective on what a session is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a database session is everything between between `PQconnectdbParams` and `PQfinish`.

If all your database sessions are very short, you won't have any performance advantages from prepared statements. You won't have any performance advantages at all, because opening database connections is very expensive and can consume a substantial part of your database server's resources if you do it often enough. The keys to happiness are long database sessions, managed by a connection pool, short transactions ans short statements.